# Why aren't my URL.Path statements getting hit

Tags: go, url-routing

Below is my function for presenting my html templates. I've recently started work on my blog page and for some reason my first and second "else if" statements aren't being hit. :

```
func handleRequest(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
    templates := populateTemplates()
    // present home.html if the request url is "/"
    if r.URL.Path == "/" {
        t := templates.Lookup("home.html")
        t.Execute(w, nil)
    } else if r.URL.Path == "blog/" {
        posts := getPosts()
        t := template.New("blog.html")
        t, _ = t.ParseFiles("blog.html")
        t.Execute(w, posts)
        return
    } else if r.URL.Path == "blog/*" {
        f := "blog/" + r.URL.Path[1:] + ".md"
        fileread, _ := ioutil.ReadFile(f)
        lines := strings.Split(string(fileread), "\n")
        status := string(lines[0])
        title := string(lines[1])
        date := string(lines[2])
        summary := string(lines[3])
        body := strings.Join(lines[4:len(lines)], "\n")
        htmlBody := template.HTML(blackfriday.MarkdownCommon([]byte(body)))
        post := Post{status, title, date, summary, htmlBody, r.URL.Path[1:]}
        t := template.New("_post.html")
        t, _ = t.ParseFiles("_post.html")
        t.Execute(w, post)
    } else {
        requestedFile := r.URL.Path[1:]
        t := templates.Lookup(requestedFile + ".html")
        if t != nil {
            err := t.Execute(w, nil)
            if err != nil {
                log.Println(err)
            }
        } else {
            w.WriteHeader(http.StatusNotFound)
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: URL paths start with a slash.

Comment: Also this `if r.URL.Path == "blog/*"`... If you assume that `==` is gonna do regexp matching for you then you're wrong, if on the other hand you have an endpoint like that, then ignore me.

Comment: what's the out of printing `r.URL.Path` before the ifs ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming the problem is with the blog urls, you could try this instead:

```
 if r.URL.Path == "/" {
 ...
 } else if r.URL.Path == "/blog" {
 ...
 } else if strings.HasPrefix(r.URL.Path,"/blog/") {
 ....     
 } else {
```

I'm hoping templates.Lookup doesn't make any file system calls, presumably it just looks them up in a map.

Also, don't do this:

```
 f := "blog/" + r.URL.Path[1:] + ".md"
 fileread, _ := ioutil.ReadFile(f)
```

What would happen if r.URL.Path[1:] was "../mysecretfile" and you had a matching file there? It's not a good idea to use external strings without cleaning them with path.Clean or similar.

Comment: Thanks Kenny, that was it. I misread the documentation with those url paths, I was convinced I had them right... :/ As for the other advice, thanks alot, this is my first web dev project I'm self-teaching on, any advice is much appreciated.

Comment: No problem. Glad you got it sorted.